# Xamarin why it hangs on permissions enabling?

Tags: android, xamarin

I done this according to Xamarin documentation, just copy-pasted a code.

So, in App.xaml.cs I have a code like this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        if (!CheckPermisions())
        {
            AbortApp(3, "Missing required permissions!");
            return ;
        }
    }

    //[...]
    
    public bool CheckPermisions()
    {
        Task<bool> v = performCheckPermisions();
        if (v.Result)
            initAppFolders();
        return v.Result;
    }

    protected async Task<bool> performCheckPermisions()
    {
        // storage read
        PermissionStatus status = await Xamarin.Essentials.Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
        if (status == PermissionStatus.Denied)
        {
            this.Context.ToLogger(EAppLogLevel.Warning, string.Format(" ! StorageRead: requesting..."));
            status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
        }
        if (status == PermissionStatus.Denied)
            return false;

        // storage write
        status = await Xamarin.Essentials.Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
        if (status == PermissionStatus.Denied)
        {
            this.Context.ToLogger(EAppLogLevel.Warning, string.Format(" ! StorageWrite: requesting..."));
            status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
        }
        if (status == PermissionStatus.Denied)
            return false;

        return true; // Task.FromResult(true);
    }
```

**The problem** is - when application started 1st time, so when the OS asks user for permissions it always hangs! :-(

And I do not understand - why?!
How to resolve this problem with hanging on 1st app run?

I tried to debug it but it never returns from `await Permissions.RequestAsync<...>()` back into debugger! :-
Of course - on OS request I clicked [Allow] in a UI prompt.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure - why it is not returning, it might be bug in VS2019 debugger or it might be bug in Xamarin... or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Could you please advice?

*Please note: I need exactly the blocking/synchronous call to permissions request! Application must stop and confirm if permissions granted. Without permissions - it must not even try to run.*

Note: VS 2019 (16.6.5); Xamarin.Forms 4.7.0.1142; Xamarin.Essentials 1.5.3.2 - so, it seems all the latest.

Thanks.

PS.
Also I tried following variants:

**Attempt# 1**

```
Task<bool> tsk = performCheckPermisions();
bool result = false;
if (tsk.IsCompleted)
{
    this.Context.ToLogger(EAppLogLevel.Info, string.Format("   . CheckPermisions: task completed without waiting..."));
    result = tsk.Result;
}
else
{
    TaskAwaiter<bool> aw = tsk.GetAwaiter();
    int counter = 0;
    while (!aw.IsCompleted)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(330);
        counter++;
        if ((counter % 10) == 0)
            this.Context.ToLogger(EAppLogLevel.Info, string.Format("   . CheckPermisions: still waiting (#{0})...", counter));
        if (counter > 100)
        {
            AbortApp(99, "Permissions were not comfirmed!");
            return false;
        }
    }
    result = aw.GetResult();
}
```

It simply hang because nor tsk.IsCompleted, nor aw.IsCompleted never became true despite user clicks to [Allow] button.

**Attempt# 2**

```
var task = Task.Run(async () => await performCheckPermisions());
if (task.IsFaulted && task.Exception != null)
{
    throw task.Exception;
}
bool result = task.Result;
this.Context.ToLogger(EAppLogLevel.Info, string.Format(" ? CheckPermisions: {0}", result));
```

It reported System.AggregateException exception: Message=One or more errors occurred. (Permission request must be invoked on main thread.); Source=mscorlib.

**Attempt# 3**

```
bool result = false;
this.isCompleted = false;
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
    async () => {
        result = await performCheckPermisions();
        this.isCompleted = true;
        }
    );

int counter = 0;
while (!this.isCompleted)
{
    Thread.Sleep(330);
    counter++;
    if ((counter % 10) == 0)
        this.Context.ToLogger(EAppLogLevel.Info, string.Format("   . CheckPermisions: still waiting (#{0})...", counter));
    if (counter > 100)
    {
        AbortApp(99, "Permissions were not comfirmed within specified timeout!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

It simply hang. It seems there is bug in Xamarin - the `await Permissions.RequestAsync<>()` call never return back to application!

Comment: Because you call `.Result` on your Task and causing a dead-lock.

Comment: How to do it then if not using .Result?

Comment: await it? Just like you do with any other task.

Comment: I just added to my querstion 3 examples of attempts which I made - as you can see all of them do not work. Permissions.RequestAsync<>() call always hangs despite any actions from my side (including await and so on).

Comment: Could you try to move the logic into `OnAppearing` method of `MainPage` ? I guess there are some limitations on `OnStart` method .

Comment: Yes, I tried - nothing changed. It is still hanging. I even make it call CheckPermissions in RunOnUiThread() - the same effect, it still hang. :-(

Answer (score 2):

- Below is the edited code. If you saw an earlier version then you saw it had problems. First entry so am new at this. *

I tried many things to get the permissions but it always hung the App, even with the awaits.

I wanted to put the permission requests as close to where the user required them (As recommended) and not abort the App. This is what I finally came up with:

1. Creating a permission interface in the Xamarin Forms project
2. Creating an Android implementation of the permissions in the Xamarin Forms Android project
3. Registered permission as dependency service in the Android Activity before loading the Forms App
4. In my WIFI Content page I created an async method that checks permission by calling the registered Dependency service
5. When I click on WIFI page scan button, it calls the async method to see if the user needs to give permission before continuing

Works like a charm.

The only caveat is that if the user selects 'Don't ask again' he will have to set location services manually. Not sure how I can tell the user since the permissions always only return Denied status. He will get a dialog informing him of insufficient permissions but no OS dialog allowing him to request permissions (Duh, because he said that that he did not want to see them)

*The permissions Interface in the Xamarin Forms project*

```
    public interface ILocationWhileInUsePermission {
    Task<PermissionStatus> CheckStatusAsync();
    Task<PermissionStatus> RequestAsync();
}
```

*Implementation on Xamarin Forms Android side*

```
public class LocationWhileInUsePermission : Xamarin.Essentials.Permissions.BasePlatformPermission, ILocationWhileInUsePermission {
    public override (string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)[] 

    RequiredPermissions => new List<(string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)> {
    (Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation, true),
    (Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation, true),
    (Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessWifiState, true),
    (Android.Manifest.Permission.ChangeWifiState, true)
}.ToArray();
```

}

*Register in the Activity.cs OnCreate before load of the App*

```
 DependencyService.Register<ILocationWhileInUsePermission, LocationWhileInUsePermission>();
 LoadApplication(new App(DI.Wrapper));
```

*In the Wifi Page create functions to invoke permissions from DependencyService and to set results*

```
private bool permissionsGranted = false;

private async Task SetAreGranted(bool granted) {
    await Task.Run(() => this.permissionsGranted = granted);
}

public async Task<bool> GetIsGranted() {
    return await Task<bool>.Run(() => { return this.permissionsGranted; });
}


public async Task<bool> ChkWifiPermissions() {
    try {
        await this.SetAreGranted(false);
        var wifiPermissions = 
            DependencyService.Get<ILocationWhileInUsePermission>();
        var status = await wifiPermissions.CheckStatusAsync();
        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted) {
            status = await wifiPermissions.RequestAsync();
            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted) {
                return await this.GetIsGranted();
            }
        }
        await this.SetAreGranted(true);
    }
    catch (Exception) {
        return await this.GetIsGranted();
    }
    return await this.GetIsGranted();
}
```

*On my WIFI Content Page, on the button click event I call the async method*

```
    private void btnDiscover_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
        if (await this.ChkWifiPermissions()) {
            this.btnSelect.IsVisible = false;
            this.ResetWifiList(new List<WifiNetworkInfo>());
            this.activity.IsRunning = true;
            App.Wrapper.WifiDiscoverAsync();
        }
        else {
            this.OnErr("Insufficient permissions to continue");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a variance to my WIFI permissions check on WIFI scan button, here is a variance that aborts on App start. It works but I prefer the one that requests closer to the usage of the permission.

This works and never hangs the App. Still the problem if the user has requested not to be asked again.

*Start by declaring service interfaces in the Xamarin Forms project to close the App, and another to check and request permissions*

```
public interface ICloseApplication {
    void CloseApp();
}

public interface ILocationWhileInUsePermission {
    Task<PermissionStatus> CheckStatusAsync();
    Task<PermissionStatus> RequestAsync();
}
```

*Then add Android OS implmentations in the Xamarin Forms Android project*

```
public class AndroidCloseApp : ICloseApplication {
    public void CloseApp() {
        Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(Android.OS.Process.MyPid());
    }
}

public class LocationWhileInUsePermission : Xamarin.Essentials.Permissions.BasePlatformPermission, ILocationWhileInUsePermission {
    public override (string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)[] 
        RequiredPermissions => new List<(string androidPermission, bool isRuntime)> {
        (Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation, true),
        (Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation, true),
        (Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessWifiState, true),
        (Android.Manifest.Permission.ChangeWifiState, true)
    }.ToArray();
}
```

*Register the Services in the Xamarin Forms Android project MainActivity.OnCreate(). BTW, the DI.Wrapper has the results from my dependency injector, with common and OS specific code*

```
DependencyService.Register<ILocationWhileInUsePermission, LocationWhileInUsePermission>();
DependencyService.Register<ICloseApplication, AndroidCloseApp>();
LoadApplication(new App(DI.Wrapper));
```

*Then in the Xamarin Forms project, in the App.OnStart() override method call an async method to request permissions and abort if necessary*

```
protected override void OnStart() {
    // This will abort the app at the start if the WIFI permissions are not given
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => {
        if (!await this.CheckPermissions()) {
            ICloseApplication closeApp = DependencyService.Get<ICloseApplication>();
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(
                App.GetText(MsgCode.Error),
                "Insufficient permissions",
                App.GetText(MsgCode.Ok));
            closeApp.CloseApp();
        }
    });
}


private async Task<bool> CheckPermissions() {
    ILocationWhileInUsePermission wifiPermissions = 
        DependencyService.Get<ILocationWhileInUsePermission>();
    PermissionStatus status = await wifiPermissions.CheckStatusAsync();
    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted) {
        status = await wifiPermissions.RequestAsync();
    }
    return status == PermissionStatus.Granted;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As Cheesebaron mentioned, you always want to use `await` when dealing with a `Task`. You can modify your example like so:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }

    protected override async void OnStart()
    {
        bool result = await CheckPermisions()
        if (!result)
        {
            AbortApp(3, "Missing required permissions!");
            return ;
        }
    }

    //[...]

    public async Task<bool> CheckPermisions()
    {
        bool v = await performCheckPermisions();
        if (v)
            initAppFolders();
        return v;
    }

    protected async Task<bool> performCheckPermisions()
    {
        // storage read
        PermissionStatus status = await Xamarin.Essentials.Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
        if (status == PermissionStatus.Denied)
        {
            this.Context.ToLogger(EAppLogLevel.Warning, string.Format(" ! StorageRead: requesting..."));
            status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageRead>();
        }
        if (status == PermissionStatus.Denied)
            return false;
        // storage write
        status = await Xamarin.Essentials.Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
        if (status == PermissionStatus.Denied)
        {
            this.Context.ToLogger(EAppLogLevel.Warning, string.Format(" ! StorageWrite: requesting..."));
            status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.StorageWrite>();
        }
        if (status == PermissionStatus.Denied)
            return false;

        return true; // Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: THIS IS NOT SOLUTION AT ALL! Because moving async/await futher in a call hierarchy does not make any sense! So, if I would call checkPerm1 -> await checkPerm2 -> await checkPerm3 -> etc or less - does not make any difference because it will hang on one level up in a call hierarchy.

Comment: @dmitry_bond I can assure you that using `await` up through the entire call hierarchy is the preferred way to use Tasks. Read any article about async/await and you will hear the exact same suggestion. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#async-all-the-way)

Comment: Sorry, the code you posted here obviously is not match my conditions. It required to add "async" specificator to the CheckPermisions() but that means exactly what I mentioned before - we move a "hang problem" one level up in a call hierarchy! So, it will hang not inside CheckPermisions() method but instead it will hang inside a mething which calls the CheckPermisions(). So, it is exactly the same problem as before.